# echo input character using blessed and cbreak

Tags: python, blessed

Writing a python script, I use blessed module to input a single character without having to press on Enter key.
Unfortunately, the character input is not echoed

```
term = Terminal()

with term.cbreak(): 
   key= term.inkey()
....
```

Is there a way to get input character echoed ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no magic answer :-)
I guess I'll just add a print(key) after each inkey() call